# How to join two separate objects using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to join two separate objects into one using geometry nodes.

For reference, here is my "starting point"
[image]

What i would like to end up with:
[image]

And here is what i tried to do to join the two geometries without success
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the "Join Geometry" problem, you need to select "Relative" in the "Object Info" node.

Comment: Ok then, i'll edit the question to remove the "bridge" part and repost it as a separate question